# maya python script - how to check the UV boundaries of models?

Tags: python, maya

I'm looking for a python function or script which could check the borders of all uv shells in the scene, including exceeds the border or too close to the border.

The scripts I found are mainly used to find all uv shells in a selected object. 
https://polycount.com/discussion/196753/maya-python-get-a-list-of-all-uv-shells-in-a-selected-object

But I want to check the borders of  all uv shells, and if there are any errors in the scene, it could show me exactly the model that is irregular.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you try to extend the script in the link? It seems to do exactly what you need and extending it for a list of meshes should be not a big deal.

Comment: agree with haggi key, you just have to use the script you linked and check for a tolerence, if x or y are above 1 or below 0 or to near this limit

Answer (score 0):

This is a very rudimentary example.  It loops over all the meshes in the scene, collecting their UV bounding boxes using `cmds.polyEvaluate`.  If it finds anything which sticks outside the bounding box supplied, it adds them to a list.  It returns two things:  first the uv bounds of the entire scene, second the list of items outside the target bounding box.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
def scene_uv_bounds(target = (0,0,1,1)):
    umin, vmin, umax, vmax  = 0, 0, 0, 0

    for item in cmds.ls(type='mesh'):
        out_of_bounds = []
        # polyEvaluate -b2 returns [(umin, umax) , (vmin, vmas)]
        uvals, vvals = cmds.polyEvaluate(item, b2=True)
        #unpack into separate values
        uumin, uumax = uvals
        vvmin, vvmax = vvals

        if uumin < target[0] or vvmin < target[1] or uumax > target[2] or vvmax > target[3]:
            out_of_bounds.append(item)

        umin = min(umin, uumin)
        umax = max(umax, uumax)
        vmin = min(vmin, vvmin)
        vmax = max(vmax, vvmax)


    return (umin, vmin, umax, vmax), out_of_bounds

#usage
uv_bounds, out_of_bounds_meshes = scene_uv_bounds()
```

Depending on your content you might need to manage the active UV set on the different items, but for simple one-channel cases this catches most cases.